# OpenCV: How to Draw bounding box around foreground object

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

I have been doing a project on Automatic detection of a person using firearms from cctv cameras.

So far i have performed background subtraction using `VibE` algorithm and canny edge detection; after that i want to perform sliding window operation on the image but due to performance issue i want the sliding window to be operated only on the extracted foreground image.

[[image: Original frame]
[[image: After Background Subtraction and Canny]

Comment: post your original image

Comment: You can get your points that are white and use boundingRect with this points... or just iterate over the image and find the min x, max x, min y and max y with white values. Then you can construct a roi around it